# Increment FOR inside a button

Tags: java, android, for-loop

So, I'm not sure if I'm not missing anything or not... (It has been a though weekend) but, let's suppose I have this:

```
for(int i=0; i<10;){
    button1.setOnClickListener(blah blah blah){
        public void onClick(View v) {
                i++;
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't let me do this, it crashes, can someone give an explanation as to why? And/or an answer on how to make this work. If you didn't get it, I'd like to make the FOR increment when the user clicks on the button. I'm pretty sure I'm missing out on something obvious and I will be pissed when I find it out... Thank you, have a nice day.

Comment: Actually what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It must be giving you stackoverflow exception

Answer (score 4):

This approach simply doesn't work. If your goal is to increment a number and run a set of code every time `button1` is clicked, you'll need to do something like this instead:

```
// somewhere in a persistent scope
int i = 0;

// somewhere in a function
button1.setOnClickListener(/* ... */) {
  public void onClick(View v) {
    ++i;
    // run your code
  }
}
```

Comment: It's just that I wanted a FOR to be able to refresh somethings every time it restarts.. Guess I'll have to do manually

Comment: @FábioSantos what are you trying to do with the even handler?

Comment: @Benten Ok, so, it's kind of a game, where it has 5 rounds, when I click the button, it sets itself to be unclickable so you can't spam it, and it changes to the color green. After this, i'd like to to change itself back to its normal state. And obviously do this for 5 rounds

Comment: I think you just want a normal for loop and then use the value of  `i` inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

It crashes because the the loop never terminates because `i` is never incremented. There is an `i++` statement inside the event handler button the button in never clicked.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, loop is not terminated util value reached so it will continue running loop, waste of CPU cycles, second of all creating and attaching new EventListener in every iteration waste of Memory. it may extending the resource limit provided to an application on device. 
solution,
*use global variable to increment value and check if it less than 10 in the callback function onClick().*